# Need assistance removing white space on nav bar

Tags: html, css

Having a hard time with this CSS code... unfortunately, I can't figure out why I maintain a white row on the bottom of the Nav bar. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I've used the Inspector tool to isolate the element that the space is part of, but I dont have border, padding, nor margin associate with it.

```css
#myNavigation,
.collapse {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: #2e3391;
}

#menu {
  margin: 0 10%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu li a {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #a4c1eb;
  border-bottom: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}

#menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #a4c1eb;
  color: #2e3391;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  border-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom-color: #f4f4f4;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  margin: -1px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="myNavigation">
    <nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data- toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
        <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a> -->
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for 
    toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul id="menu-nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#home-slider">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About </a></li>
          <li><a href="#join">How To </a></li>
          <li><a href="#support">Support</a></li>
          <li><a href="#media">News &amp; Media</a></li>
          <li><a href="#events">Schedules &amp; Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="#alumni">The Corner</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please don't forget to vote the answer if it helps. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap has a `min-height` of 50px on `.navbar` class. Since your nav is 41px is shows an extra whitespace below, https://jsfiddle.net/smhtp5c8/1/

Just update your css with,

```
#menu {
    ...
    min-height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
@user8379561 Either you have to override the .navbar css or you can also use css specificity like above one.